# Select row with most recent date per user where date is more than current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

My table is:

```
 id  user   date
 ---|-----|------------|
 1  | ab  | 2011-03-04 |
 2  | ab  | 2016-03-04 |
 3  | cd  | 2009-03-04 |
 4  | cd  | 2013-03-03 |
 5  | ef  | 2009-03-03 |
```

I need to select each distinct user with :

"update" > date more than current date

Result would be:

```
 id  user   date
 ---|-----|------------|
 2  | ab  | 2016-03-04 |
 5  | ef  | 2016-03-03 |
```

"expired" > date less than current date

Result would be:

```
 id  user   date
 ---|-----|------------|
 3  | cd  | 2009-03-04 |
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tmp t1
WHERE t1.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
FROM tmp t2 WHERE t2.user = t1.user
AND YEAR(MAX(t2.date))<(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1))
order by user asc
```

It doesn't work. Result-set has 0 rows.
Any ideas? Thanks. It'll help me so much..

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@TimBiegeleisen` for the answer..
I've tried this code and it works..

This code for showing the 'update' rows:

```
select a.* from tmp a 
inner join
(select user, max(date) as date from tmp group by user)
b on a.user=b.user and a.date=b.date
where year(a.date +interval 1 year) >= year(current_date())
order by a.user
```

and this for showing the 'expired' rows:

```
select a.* from tmp a
inner join
(select user, max(date) as date from tmp group by user)
b on a.user=b.user and a.date=b.date
where year(a.date +interval 1 year) < year(current_date())
order by a.user
```

I hope my question and all the answers can help other's problems..

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are in a peculiar format of `MM/dd/YYYY`, which may pose a problem for you when trying any of the answers given here.  You should convert `04/03/2011` to `2011-04-03`.  That being said, assuming your `date` column really is a MySQL date type, then the following query will give you all distinct "update" users:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user, t1.date, 'update' AS status
FROM antivirus t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM antivirus
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING MAX(date) >= CURDATE()
) t2
ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.date = t2.date
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8785/1)

Note that in my Fiddle I had to modify the format of the date inputs from your sample table.

If you also want the "expired" users in the same query, than you can add `UNION ALL` plus the following:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user, t1.date, 'expired' AS status
FROM antivirus t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM antivirus
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING MAX(date) < CURDATE()
) t2
ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your data.  The query should be giving you results.  Wait, I'll set up a SQL Fiddle for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: most likely explanation for the behavior is that OP `date` column is a VARCHAR in format `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` format, which MySQL isn't going to convert to `DATE` datatype, without an explicit `STR_TO_DATE` function.

Comment: @spencer7593 I noticed this as well.  No one's query will run on his raw data because of the format problem.  I'm testing my query now in Fiddle and it works after massaging the format of his dates.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM tmp where YEAR(date)>=(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) order by date desc"  > I use this query to show the update fields and it works.. But I need to show the expired rows that is not showed in update.. I mean if that row is showed in update so it will not showed in expired.. please help me

Comment: I think your query is wrong, and I think you should use a `UNION` of two separate queries to get your result set.  Did you even bother to read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

For dates greater than the current date:

```
select distinct user
from t
where `update` >= curdate();
```

Actually, I think you want a `group by`:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having max(`date`) >= curdate();
```

This will also work for earlier dates.

Comment: i'm sorry but "update" and "expired" are not name of columns or table.. it is just status that i make..

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

"It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive of the behavior you observe. It doesn't describe whether the query is executing and is returning unexpected results, or whether the query is returning an error.

The values shown for `date` values are in an odd non-MySQL format. Standard format for `DATE` values is `YYYY-MM-DD`. This leaves us wondering what the actual *datatype* of the column named `date`. If it's a character string, with the month and day preceding the year, that presents problems in comparisons. String comparisons are done character by character, from left to right.

The use of the `YEAR()` function is very strange in this context. You say you want to compare "date" values. The `YEAR` function extracts the year value from a date. So it looks like your query is only going to be comparing a year.

And again, if the argument to the `YEAR()` function isn't a `DATE` datatype, there's going to be an implicit conversion of that argument to `DATE`... and for that implicit conversion to work correctly, the string will need to be in a format like 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Also, it looks like the subquery is using an aggregate function `MAX()` in a `WHERE` clause. That's not valid. The predicates in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated when the rows are accessed. The value of the aggregate function will not be available until *after* the rows are accessed, and the group by operation is performed. If you need a condition on the aggregate, then that can go into a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: i'm sorry for being improper.. yah i check my database and my date format is yyyy-mm-dd.. so maybe the format is not the problem..

Comment: "SELECT * FROM tmp where YEAR(date)>=(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) order by date desc" > I use this query to show the update rows and it works.. But I need to show the expired rows that is not showed in update.. I mean if that row is showed in update so it will not showed in expired.. please help me

Comment: @Fiki This isn't the way to use Stack Overflow.  You should be reviewing each answer and commenting on whether each approach is helping with your problem.